# How to control AirPort wireless radio from the command line?

Tags: macos, terminal, network, airport, command-line

I want to know how to control (specifically turn off) the networking (specifically AirPort - I want to turn off the radio) from the command line (specifically from bash in Terminal.app, being run by me) as a user (no sudo privileges or admin priviliges). You CAN turn off AirPort as a user, but I need to do this from the command line – as a user.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [OSX Daily - Enable and Disable AirPort Wireless from the Command Line in Mac OS X](http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/31/enable-disable-airport-wireless-connections-command-line/).  Quote:

> **Turn Airport Off via Command Line**
>   `networksetup -setairportpower airport off`
>
> **Turn Airport On via Command Line**
>   `networksetup -setairportpower airport on`
>
> You won’t see any confirmation in the Terminal that the command
>   succeeded or failed, but if you watch the AirPort menu icon you will
>   see the bars disappear indicating the wireless interface is turned
>   off, or reappear indicating that wireless is activated again.

**NOTE:** In OS X Lion, use the hardware name above instead of `airport`,
e.g. `networksetup -setairportpower en1 off`.

Comment: This a great answer, but you should specify that they need to replace `airport` with the network adapter name their computer uses. For my MacBook Pro, it's `en1`.

Comment: Great point.  The article I quoted to even had a similar comment.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful, a friend of mine is on a computer where when you try to change airport to off it pops something up for the admin password. This seemed easier than fixing that - now he has two workflows for connecting automatically to various networks at times of the day and stuff like that.

Comment: Beware that it is not always `en1`. To find out what it is on your computer, you can use either `networksetup -listallhardwareports` or `ifconfig`.