# How to control Bluetooth wireless radio from the command line?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, terminal, bluetooth, command-line

This question is almost the same as [my previous question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46904/how-to-control-airport-wireless-radio-from-the-command-line/46907#46907), but with one major difference; I want to turn on/off Bluetooth from the command line (bash or similar), *NOT* from AppleScript - the answers for this I saw on superuser all used AppleScript.

I would guess that `networksetup` might be useful but have no idea what interface(s) to interact with - I would like an answer including a complete command I can run (and understand) - if device model matters, it's Snow Leopard on `MacBook2,1` to `MacBook7,1`, except `MacBook5,1`, and if you can only do for 6,1 and 7,1 that's fine.

Comment: You can run AppleScript from the command line using `osascript -e "<applescript goes here>"` if popping up windows is the only issue you have with using it.

Comment: I don't like AppleScript as a language; it tends to be verbose.

Comment: Also, Assistive Devices aren't enabled and I can't admin on this computer.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**[Blueutil](http://www.frederikseiffert.de/blueutil/)** is a neat little command line tool to do this. It's free and comes with the source code.  If you have [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed, you can install it via `brew install blueutil`.

> **Usage:**
>
> **Print bluetooth status**
>   `blueutil`
>
> **Switch bluetooth on**
>   `blueutil --power 1` or `blueutil -p 1`
>
> **Switch bluetooth off**
>   `blueutil --power 0` or `blueutil -p 0`

Works just fine on a Macbook Pro running Lion (10.7.3) and Mac mini running Snow Leopard (10.6.8). You will get some errors if you switch off the bluetooth whilst a magic mouse is connected, it still works though :)

Comment: Thank you. I'll accept this soon but don't like to accept within 6 hours after posting (if you can do this without downloading anything, just using built-in OS X that would also be very nice so I'm waiting to see if someone suggests that).

Comment: @Andrew The other way you could do this without downloading anything is by killing (and restarting) the bluetooth daemon process (blued) as follows. However, I would recommend **not to use this method** as it plays havoc with the bluetooth preferences pane and the bluetooth status icon in the menubar, as they now will not be able to update themselves any more. To stop the bluetooth daemon: `sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist`. To restart the bluetooth daemon: `sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist`

Comment: @Andrew Ah, I just noticed in an earlier comment you said you couldn't "admin on this computer". If I've understood that correctly then my previous comment won't work as you need to type an admin password to `sudo`

Comment: It's OK, `blueutil` worked fine.

Comment: blueutil has some questionable code included. It attempts to use an osax called XMail. XMail is a free osax for Mac OS X allowing you to send e-mail from AppleScript. Be careful of software you give admin privileges to. Here's a message I got in Terminal when I ran the installer but before I authorized admin privileges. Error loading /Library/ScriptingAdditions/XMail.osax/Contents/MacOS/XMail: dlopen(/Library/ScriptingAdditions/XMail.osax/Contents/MacOS/XMail, 262): no suitable image found.

Comment: I didn't give it an admin privilege. I just copied out the binary.

Comment: Yeah, just copied the binary to /usr/local/bin. But where's that questionable code? Took a look at the included source and it looked legit, didn't build it though.

Comment: This was a great answer and BTW, you can `brew install blueutil` to easily install it. They seem to have changed the command line flags, use `blueutil power 1` to turn on bluetooth.

Comment: And `blueutil power 0` to turn off.

Comment: Mostly expected an old Mac answer to fail on newer Intel-based machines, but it works for macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 too!  Was a charm since my Bluetooth service was not picking up my devices from login this morning again.  This was able to toggle the service when the Pref Pane was not!  I also like shorter commands the community supports in some cases, like opposed to the other `launchctl` answer below.  `blueutil -p <\d>` worked for me like in this answer, unlike the comments above.

Answer (score 11):

The following worked for me (OSX 10.7.5) to turn bluetooth ON from the command line (using commands found [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2619301?start=0&tstart=0)):

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth ControllerPowerState -int 1

sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.blued.plist
```

(I ran into the problem that I disabled bluetooth and then on the next system start I could not use the wireless keyboard anymore... so no logging in from the screen but I could log in via ssh. And it was not clear to me how to install software such as `blueutil` from the command line as suggested by @binarybob )

Comment: I can't sudo on this computer, as per one  of my other comments, but this is still nice to know. I unpacked blueutil graphically and then ran the executable from the command line, so I had to already have set it up.

Comment: As binarybob previously said in his [comment](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47503/how-to-control-bluetooth-wireless-radio-from-the-command-line#comment-54464), this can confuse the GUI

Answer (score 1):

This opensource mac command line tool supposedly does that, and a whole lot more:

https://github.com/guarinogabriel/Mac-CLI

> The ultimate tool to manage your Mac. It provides a huge set of command line commands that automatize the usage of your OS X system.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for macOS 13 Ventura which does not require 3rd party utility:

`/usr/bin/defaults write /private/var/root/Library/Preferences/com.apple.BTServer.plist defaultPoweredState off`

`/usr/bin/killall -HUP bluetoothd`