# How to disable Bluetooth Sharing via terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I want to disable the Bluetooth Sharing that is located in the sharing preference section. I want to be able to disable it via terminal, does anyone have an idea on how to do that?

Comment: maybe this will help you http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47503/how-to-control-bluetooth-wireless-radio-from-the-command-line

Comment: @Buscar웃 that seems to be just to disable bluetooth, I want to disable the sharing feature.

Comment: This set of commands may help by [disabling Bluetooth Discoverable Mode.](http://krypted.com/mac-security/disabling-bluetooth-discoverable-mode/)

Comment: The .pref file is located at ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.Bluetooth.<HardwareUUID>.plist, and the specific property in the .plist is PrefKeyServicesEnabled. Toggling Bluetooth Sharing on and off in the Sharing Pref pane off changes the boolean value of this property in the .plist file. Kicking OS X to actually make the change I'm still investigating.

Comment: @IconDaemon I dont seem to see this inside of the plist file. Have you discovered anything else?

Comment: Haven't discovered anything yet. I'm running Yosemite on my Mac and I see this value toggle back and forth in the .plist whenever I check (and uncheck) the checkbox. Perhaps Mavericks did it differently. One thing to help find out what files are changing is to have the both the Preferences folder and the ByHost folder open in separate windows, sorted by date with newest first. Then turn on (or off) Bluetooth Sharing, **close the Sharing Prefpane**, and see what files have been modified in both folders. This is how I found the PrefKeyServicesEnabled property. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'm using for Yosemite:

First, grab $hardwareUUID:

```
hardwareUUID=$(/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep "Hardware UUID" | awk -F ": " '{print $2}')
```

Then loop through existing users and set to "Disabled"

```
for USER_HOME in /Users/*
  do
    USER_UID=`basename "${USER_HOME}"`
    if [ ! "${USER_UID}" = "Shared" ] 
     then 
      if [ ! -d "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences ]
       then
        mkdir -p "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences
        chown "${USER_UID}" "${USER_HOME}"/Library
        chown "${USER_UID}" "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences
      fi
      if [ ! -d "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences/ByHost ]
       then
        mkdir -p "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences/ByHost
        chown "${USER_UID}" "${USER_HOME}"/Library
        chown "${USER_UID}" "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences
        chown "${USER_UID}" "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences/ByHost
      fi
      if [ -d "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences/ByHost ]
       then
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :PrefKeyServicesEnabled"  "$USER_HOME"/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.Bluetooth.$hardwareUUID.plist
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :PrefKeyServicesEnabled bool false"  "$USER_HOME"/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.Bluetooth.$hardwareUUID.plist
        chown "${USER_UID}" "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.Bluetooth.$hardwareUUID.plist
      fi
    fi
  done
```

If you just want the chunk that actually disables the value, see below:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :PrefKeyServicesEnabled"  "$USER_HOME"/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.Bluetooth.$hardwareUUID.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Add :PrefKeyServicesEnabled bool false"  "$USER_HOME"/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.Bluetooth.$hardwareUUID.plist
chown "${USER_UID}" "${USER_HOME}"/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.Bluetooth.$hardwareUUID.plist
```