# How can I turn off Bluetooth with only keyboard actions?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, trackpad, shortcut

A trackpad in another room was interfering with my ability to use my laptop's native trackpad, such that I could not click on anything. I wanted to either turn off bluetooth or disconnect the offending device.

I used Finder to get into Bluetooth settings but then I was stuck. I could not figure out a keyboard shortcut to get to the button to turn off bluetooth nor to disconnect the connected trackpad.

[image]

Comment: hah. I wrote a script that did this exact thing once. I'll share it with you.

Comment: See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47503/how-to-control-bluetooth-wireless-radio-from-the-command-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the Finder, type `command + shift + u` and open Script Editor by selecting it and typing `command + o`. In a new script, type (since you can't highlight to copy)

```
tell application "System Events"
    click button "Turn Bluetooth Off" of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
end tell
```

and then type `command + r` to run the script. The trackpad should now be disconnected.

Comment: Perfect! Does exactly what I need and gives me a good template for similar simple scripts, as I haven't done any AppleScripting before.

Comment: I got `error "System Events got an error: Can’t get application process \"System Preferences\"." number -1728 from application process "System Preferences"` in Mojave

Comment: Because System Preferences has to be running. You'll get that error if it's not.

Comment: As of 2022, os 12.4, I always get the error `System Events got an error: Can’t get button "Turn Bluetooth Off" of window 1 of application process "System Preferences".` whether System Preferences is open or not. You also need to press `Command + n` for a new script.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a TouchBar Mac Book:
Invoke **Siri** via TouchBar and simply say **"Turn Off Bluetooth"**

If Siri is not enabled, it will prompt you to enable first.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206993

*First time used Siri on my Mac!*

Comment: Dont need TouchBar just cmd+space Siri

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to enable VoiceOver (CMD + F5) and using this to keyboard navigate the bluetooth settings panel with TAB and ENTER plus the arrow keys.

That let's you both turn off bluetooth and disconnect specific devices.

Comment: In 2019 this was the only option that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just the primary click function you are missing and you still have control of where you move the mouse you likely also have the function to right click.

Therefore, if you can bring up Bluetooth settings with your keyboard using spotlight search, you can then right click on the device you need to disconnect.

No script necessary!

I just did it.

Answer (score 0):

This works in BigSur 11.2.3:

1. Go to **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts**
2. Check `Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls`

Then, in future:

1. `Cmd <Space>` to open Spotlight Search
2. Type `bluetooth` and select the `Bluetooth` settings app
3. Press the tab key to move focus to the `Turn Bluetooth On` or `Turn Bluetooth Off` button
4. Press space to activate the button