# Can I disable bluetooth

Tags: macos, bluetooth, login, startup

I’d like to have Bluetooth disabled automatically when I login to my user account. Is there any way to achieve this?

I’m running macOS Sierra, and have blueutil installed.

Comment: Log in or Log out

Comment: @Buscar웃 out and back in

Comment: check this out if it does what you want https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191490/46541

Comment: ty, testing now

Comment: `error "System Events got an error: Can’t get application process \"System Preferences\"." number -1728 from application process "System Preferences”`