# Enable trackpad via keyboard

Tags: macos, keyboard, trackpad, settings, accessibility

I prefer to disable the trackpad on my macbook when an external mouse is attached via bluetooth, so that I don't accidentally hit it and to discourage me from using it, which I find un-ergonomic.

However, sometimes I'll move the macbook to the sofa or another room and forget the bluetooth mouse. In those cases I'm stuck with no mouse controller at all. So I would like to be able to re-enable the trackpad. However, I find that hard to do, using just the keyboard.

This is how far I've gotten:

[image: pointer control options in the accessibility settings]

It's that second checkbox I need to toggle, but I can't find a way to manipulate it without a mouse. Can it be done?

I actually did manage it using "Mouse Keys", but... mouse keys are quite annoying, since they disable the regular action of nine buttons on the keyboard. I also tried "Head Pointer", which is even more annoying in my opinion.

So I'm hoping there is some way to use the keyboard to do it, I might have overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable full keyboard access to easily navigate the on-screen controls using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and arrow key.

Go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts and check the checkbox shown towards the bottom that reads, Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls.

[image]

Now with the above set up, you can simply open System Preferences using Spotlight (which itself can be launched using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>), then use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to move focus to the System Preferences search field. Now type *Mouse and trackpad* and select the result that reads *Mouse and trackpad easier to use*.

[image]

This would take you to the desired preference pane. Now you can easily use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to navigate to the required checkbox and toggle the setting.

[image]

P.S.: With full keyboard access, on-screen controls can be navigated using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> and/or arrow keys. A control can be activated or toggled using the <kbd>Space</kbd> or the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, and dialogue boxes dismissed using the the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disconnect your Bluetooth Mouse, just turn off Bluetooth.

You will need a (free) utility called `blueutil` to turn it off.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/47508/119271) for full details on where to obtain and how to use.

You can use [AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19753879/4703819) to disable Bluetooth as well.

Once disconnected, your track pad will begin working again.